# Sql update join two values to set another value

Tags: mysql

Ive previously got help with making this query below, but now i noticed it doesnt work properly. Seems like it updated only on checking father.Blood and not both mother and father

```
update DB1 p join
       DB1 father
       on father.id = p.father_id and father.Blood = 'A_test' join
       DB1 mother
       on mother.id = p.mother_id and mother.Blood = 'A_test'
    set p.Blood = 'B_result';
```

So i want the child (p.Blood) to be updated with 'B_result' as long as father AND mother have 'A_test' value

I also tried to set father value to C_test and mother value to F_test and wanted p.Blood to be set at G_result, but when I checked the updated rows after running this query I see that p.Blood is updated with the G_result BUT father and mother value is not matching what i said.

ex:

```
update DB1 p join
           DB1 father
           on father.id = p.father_id and father.Blood = 'C_test' join
           DB1 mother
           on mother.id = p.mother_id and mother.Blood = 'F_test'
        set p.Blood = 'G_result';
```

Is there any errors to the code im using? (In phpMyAdmin) or do i need to add a IF or ONLY IF or anything..?

I also need the query to skip those entries wich already have p.Blood value 'myvalue' OR 'myvalue2'

Appreciate any advice :P Im still a noob so would need good explanations :P

Comment: Perhaps the values were already G_result for some of the rows that don't match your conditions.  Your query looks like it would do what you want, assuming that `id` is a unique key in the `father` and `mother` tables.

Comment: It looks like it's doing exactly what you want it to when I try to reproduce this in SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5142cb/1  As Gordon pointed out, you might have some sort of data issues.  Could you post an SQL fiddle with the data that you are trying to work on?